# Find following x occurrences after a string with PHP regex?

Tags: php, regex

I'd like to preg_match all div ids **following** the p tag with name="groups". How do I write this expression in PHP? (The html is malformed so I can't use XPath ...)

```
<p name="groups">
  <div id="55">fifty-five</div>
  <div id="65">sixty-five</div>
  <div id="75">seventy-five</div>
</p>
```

The ideal output would be something like:

```
  array
    55
    65
    75

  array
    fifty-five
    sixty-five
    seventy-five
```

Comment: Please post the code that uses XPath and fails.

Comment: `The html is malformed so I can't use XPath` - and you think regex will play nicer? Think again...

Comment: [don't use regex to parse html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Comment: Can't you just point me to a decent "match anything after this" resource? I know regex will work and not XPath - that is why I included it in the question ...

Comment: The thought that regexes will work is self-deception in general case. There's always a relatively high possibility that small changes in the HTML will result in unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: @dani *"Can't you just point me to a decent "match anything after this" resource?"* - No. *" I know regex will work and not XPath"* - wrong again. You just have not tried enough to get XPath to work.

Comment: following the p tag? no way.maybe you meant children or descendants of the p tag?

Comment: btw-the dom extension recovers from soup html pretty well. you can also run the html through the html tidy extension first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst using regex to *parse* html is usually not good, using it to *match* certain pieces of html for limited jobs can be fine.

Here's the regex:

```
<p name="groups">(\s*<div id="([0-9]+)">([a-z\-]+)</div>)+\s*</p>
```